# How to fix import error for Azure storage-blob on next.js?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, next.js13

I'm trying to download videos and thumbnails from my azure storage blob container. For some reason, I keep getting this error below.

I'm using next.js to do this. The `@azure/storage-blob` that I'm using is the latest. I tried the older version but I get the same errors.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**Error**

```
Attempted import error: 'StorageSharedKeyCredential' is not exported from '@azure/storage-blob' (imported as 'StorageSharedKeyCredential').

Attempted import error: 'SASProtocol' is not exported from '@azure/storage-blob' (imported as 'SASProtocol').

Attempted import error: 'generateBlobSASQueryParameters' is not exported from '@azure/storage-blob' (imported as 'generateBlobSASQueryParameters').

Attempted import error: 'ContainerSASPermissions' is not exported from '@azure/storage-blob' (imported as 'ContainerSASPermissions').
```

**Code**

```
"use client"; 

import { BlobServiceClient, ContainerSASPermissions, SASProtocol, StorageSharedKeyCredential, generateBlobSASQueryParameters } from '@azure/storage-blob';

const accountName: string = process.env.AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME || "";
const accountKey: string = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_ACCESS_KEY || "";

const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);

console.log("Shared key: ", sharedKeyCredential);

const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`, sharedKeyCredential);

const containerName: string = process.env.AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME || "";

const container_client = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const THUMBNAIL_FOLDER_PATH: string = "/thumbnail/"
const VIDEO_FOLDER_PATH: string = "/video/"


async function get_thumbnail_from_blob(thumbnail_name: string) {

    const blob_client = container_client.getBlobClient(thumbnail_name);
    const blob_data = await blob_client.download(0);

    return blob_data;

}

async function get_video_from_blob(vidoe_name: string) {

    const blob_client = container_client.getBlobClient(vidoe_name);

    const sasOptions = {
        containerName,
        protocol: SASProtocol.Https,
        permission: ContainerSASPermissions.parse('r').toString(),
        expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 3600 * 1000)
    };

    const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(sasOptions, sharedKeyCredential).toString();

    return `${blob_client.url}?${sasToken}`;
}


const getBlobs = async(containerBlobName: string) => {

    const blobs: Array<any> = [];
    const blob_names: string[] = [];

    const blob_list = container_client.listBlobsFlat();

    const loader = {
        [THUMBNAIL_FOLDER_PATH]: get_thumbnail_from_blob,
        [VIDEO_FOLDER_PATH]: get_video_from_blob
    };

    const loaderFunction = loader[containerBlobName];

    for await (const blob of blob_list) {
        blobs.push(await loaderFunction(blob.name));
        blob_names.push(blob.name);
    }

    return [blobs, blob_names]

}


export const get_thumbnails = async () => {
    const [thumbnails, thumbnail_names] = await getBlobs(THUMBNAIL_FOLDER_PATH);

    console.log("thumbnail: ", thumbnail_names);
    return [thumbnails, thumbnail_names]
}


export const get_videos = async () => {
    const [videos, video_names] = await getBlobs(VIDEO_FOLDER_PATH);
    return [videos, video_names]
}
```

Comment: turns out, it's only allowed in node.js and not in browser for security reasons. I could only use SAS token that I had to create for the container.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting this error is because you are running the code on the client side (using `"use client"` directive) and these artifacts are only available in Node runtime.

You would need to move the code to generate SAS Token to server-side. If your code is intended to run on the server, then please remove `"use client"` directive from your code and you should not get the error.

Comment: No, even without "use client", it didn't work for me.

Comment: Is your code running on client side or server side?